# Convert HTML to Image using html2canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, html2canvas

I developed a simple `div` element which contains text.

I Tried to convert the `html` to `PNG` using `html2canvas` and output it as an image in another image. While running it in my local server , Rendering is initialized successfully based on the console.log

`118ms html2canvas: Canvas renderer initialized (1350x18 at 8,8) with scale 1`

But the output image is not appending in the assigned `div` element.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**JAVASCRIPT**

```js
function myFunction () { 
   html2canvas(document.getElementById("hi"), {
       onrendered: function(canvas) {
           theCanvas = canvas;
           document.body.appendChild(canvas);
           // Convert and download as image 
           Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
           document.getElementById("img-out").append(canvas);
      }
   });
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<html>
   <script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>

  <body onload="myFunction()">
    <div id ="hi">
      Hi There !
    </div>
    </br></br></br></br></br></br>
    <div id="img-out"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get canvas as an image source & display the image on your page.
Please note that if you are using latest version of html2canvas library, 'onrendered' function is deprecated. Use the following script instead

```
function myFunction (){
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#hi")).then(canvas => {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        var img = document.createElement("img"); // create an image object
            image.src = canvas.toDataURL(); // get canvas content as data URI
        document.getElementById('img-out').appendChild(image); 
    });
}
```